# Error in opening a file residing on server through utl_file.open!

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to open a file residing in data base server  ,
i used 
  SELECT * 
  FROM V$PARAMETER 
  WHERE NAME = 'utl_file_dir'
to find out directory path.

When i am executing this code i am getting this error.
error coming "ORA-29283: invalid file operation"

```
declare
    v_file_handler utl_file.file_type;
    p_dir varchar2(100):='/d04/data/edi/inbound';
    v_no  number:=1;
    v_file varchar2(30):='ut_file.txt';
    begin
    if utl_file.is_open(v_file_handler) then 
    dbms_output.put_line('Already opened');
    else
    v_file_handler:= utl_file.fopen(p_dir,v_file,'r');
    utl_file.putf(v_file_handler,'program %s\n',sysdate);
    dbms_output.put_line('not opened');
    end if;
    exception
    when others then
    dbms_output.put_line(sqlerrm);
    end;
```

Comment: v_file_handler:= utl_file.fopen(p_dir,v_file,'r');

Answer (score 1):

```
v_file_handler:= utl_file.fopen(p_dir,v_file,'r');
utl_file.putf(v_file_handler,'program %s\n',sysdate);
```

You're opening a file for reading and attempting to write to it. That's bound to throw the
error.

From [Oracle documentation:](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/u_file.htm#i1003526)

```
UTL_FILE.FOPEN (
   location     IN VARCHAR2,
   filename     IN VARCHAR2,
   open_mode    IN VARCHAR2,
   max_linesize IN BINARY_INTEGER) 

open_mode Specifies how the file is opened. 
Modes include:  r -- read text
```

Also,

> **ORA-29283: invalid file operation**
>
> **Cause**:  An attempt was made to read from a file or directory that does not exist, or file or directory access was denied by the operating system.
>
> **Action**:    Verify file and directory access privileges on the file system, and if reading, verify that the file exists.

Comment: Refer to the ORA error description. Ensure that the file exists and you/oracle user group has permissions to access the files.

Comment: Hi, Please tell mw: What do you think about this https://stackoverflow.com/q/59756676/811293?

Answer (score 1):

utl_file_dir has been [deprecated in favour](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/u_file.htm#i996762) of [CREATE DIRECTORY](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_5007.htm#i2061958)